# Detect when a div appears (jquery)

Tags: html, jquery

Here is my problem:
when I click submit button on a poorly completed form, a div appears with errors and I want the additional text to appear.
My question: how to detect the appearance of this div (error) from the click?

```js
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("document").on('click', 'button', function() {
        if ($("#errors").length) {
          $("<h1>Something</h1>").insertAfter(".className");
        }
      });
    });
)}
```

My code works but only after a second click(and it makes sense) but I want from the first click.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; there are missing closing brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pure CSS:

- inside the error box, make an absolute positioned div.(and style
  it how ever you want)
- after that on the CSS syntax Select the div as a
  child for the main Error box.

So automatically when error appear it means the error box has a class (and also it means your syntax will work because the dive you've created is a child for the error box.)

Comment: Thank you for your response Ali. But I want to know if it is possible to do it in jquery. It has become an obsession